# Use gradle to retrieve a maven artefact in a repo with a non standard layout

Tags: maven, build, gradle, ivy

I have a gradle build script and I'm trying to get at the dependency [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.10_0.13/1.5.1/sbt-idea-1.5.1.jar).

As you can see the name (sbt-idea) cannot be simply substituted into the url after the group because there is a non-standard post fix `'_2.10_0.13'` to the name in the middle of the url.

I am unable to configure the maven repository type as it demands a pure convention approach

I can configure the ivy repository type to generate the correct jar url but sadly it demands that a corresponding `ivy.xml` (or any other name I configure it to use) in an `ivy.xml` format exist at the location. I cannot convince it to require a `.pom` instead.

Is it possible to achieve what I want to achieve using repositories in gradle?

Comment: You need to configure maven pattern? Isn't it here more or less what You're looking for: https://github.com/Opalo/gradle-workshops/blob/master/intermediate/multimodule/client/solution/build.gradle ?

Comment: that may well be it. i shall give that a whirl and get back to you. if it's right i suggest you promote your response to a full answer and i'll mark you as winner

Comment: so, that works but it marks mavenRepo as a deprecated method... I shall search for an up to date mechanism that allows me to do something similar... but I was unable to find anything in the docs that looked promising. if you know of something not deprecated that would be champion. for now, i'd suggest promoting your comment to an answer and i shall tick it as the solution unless anyone else can suggest the more correct solution in the mean time. any, many thanks

Comment: ok, so I've blasted through the gradle code and found the DefaultMavenArtifactRepository which implements MavenArtifactRepository and the only properties that you can set are url and artifactUrls, so trying the same thing via the preferred mechanism seems impossible at the moment.

Comment: what i'm not sure i like is the fact that ivy supports reading poms in maven compatible repos but the gradle ivy does not support that functionality. the gradle maven repository enforcing the convention is probably more idiomatic of the way maven works and is supposed to work, so less of an issue with the deprecation of pattern support in the latest maven repos